# Installing with pip: please set LZO_DIR to where the lzo source lives

Tags: python-2.7, pip, installation, lzo

I tried to install bx-python (https://github.com/bxlab/bx-python) with pip

```
pip install bx-python
```

from my anaconda path. The exception I got was

> Exception: please set LZO_DIR to where the lzo source lives

I am not sure where this lzo source is living and why I have to set it.

Could you explain me why this error is happening and how to fix it?
Thanks!

Python 2.7 on Windows

Answer (score 1):

You need lzo sources because [`bx-python` depends on `python-lzo`](https://github.com/bxlab/bx-python/blob/master/setup.py#L20) and `python-lzo` is only distributed in [source form in C](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-lzo/1.11) hence `pip` wants to compile it and for compilation `python-lzo` requires lzo sources. You have to [install `liblzo2`](https://github.com/jd-boyd/python-lzo#installation).

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering this question. Unfortunately I also have trouble installing liblzo2, so I will try to set up a Linux now - windows and spyder are not really fun here